# Unable to insert GIF in Markdown header

Tags: github, markdown

this README.md code used to render properly on GitHub profile until recently:

```
# Hello <img src="images/wave.gif" width="25px">, 

- ✝️
- Currently in 
- Playand  occasionally
```

I notice that inline GIF does not work with Markdown heading #, ##, ###, but works fine otherwise.

Any way to insert inline GIF in my header?

Thank you in advance

Tried this code block, which did not render correctly:

```
# Hello <img src="images/wave.gif" width="25px">, 

- ✝️
- Currently in 
- Playand  occasionally
```